# O TextView não aparece por algum motivo

Tags: android, xml

Gostaria de fazer algo assim no XML:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já tentei com LinearLayout mas eu não estou conseguindo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/colorBackground"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:weightSum="1" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:text="Título Legal"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:textSize="40px"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="280px"
    android:layout_height="400px"
    android:background="@drawable/img1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Oie"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="281px" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Se eu colocar o texto aonde está a imagem, o texto aparece, mas quando eu tento colocar um pouco pra frente da imagem, ele não aparece (android:layout_marginLeft="281px").

Obs: A cor de fundo é preto (@color/colorBackground) e a cor do texto é branca (@color/colorText).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A declaração das bibliotecas do Android no *root* do seu *layout* estava duplicada e escrita de forma incorreta. Já corrigi isso na edição do seu post.

Porém, criei um *layout* novo e testei no meu app. Está funcionando do jeito que deseja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_group"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_left"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_alert_error" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_right"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Texto 1" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Texto 2" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Texto 3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

A imagem fica no *layout_left* e os textos no *layout_right*. O *layout_group* serve para centralizar os dois layouts igualmente na tela.